# RabbitMQ with EventMachine and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon, rabbitmq, eventmachine, ruby-on-rails-3.2

we are currently planning a rails 3.2.2 application where we use RabbitMQ. We would like to run several kind of workers (and several instances of a worker) to process messages from different queues. The workers are written in ruby and are laying in the lib directory of the rails app.

Some of the workers needs the rails framework (active record, active model...) and some of them don't. The first worker should be called every minute to check if updates are available. The other workers should process the messages from their queues when messages (which are send by the first worker) are present and do some (time consuming) stuff with it.

So far, so good. My problem is, that I only have little experiences with messaging systems like RabbitMQ and no experiences with the rails interaction between them. So I'm wondering what the best practices are to get the two playing with each other. Here are my requirements again:

- Rails 3.2.2 app
- RabbitMQ
- Several kind of workers
- Several instances of one worker
- Control the amount of workers out of rails
- Workers are doing time consuming tasks, so they have to be async
- Only a few workers needs the rails framework. The others are just ruby files with some dependencies like Net or File

I was looking for some solution and came up with two possibilities:

**Using amqp with EventMachine in a new thread**

Of course, I don't want my rails app to be blocked when a new worker is created. The worker should run in another thread and do its work asynchronously. And furthermore, it should not start a new instance of my rails application. It should only require the things the worker needs.

But in some articles they say that there are some issues with Passenger. And another fact that I don't like is, that we are using webbrick for development and we ought to include workarounds for that too. It would be possible to switch to another webserver like thin, but I don't have any experience with that either.

**Using some kind of daemonizing**

Maybe its possible to run workers as a daemon, but I don't know how much overhead this would come up with, or how I can control the amount of workers.

Hope someone can advise a good solution for that (and I hope I made myself clear ;)

Comment: I'm working on the same thing and have not found a good answer, hopefully someone will see this.

Comment: i hope so too ;) and if you find some useful information or even a solution, pls tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that AMQP is a big shot to kill your problem. Have you tried to use Resque? The backed Redis database has some neat features (like publish/subscribe and blocking list pop) which make it very interesting as a message queue, and Resque is very easy to use in any Rails app.

The workers are daemonized, and you decide which worker of your pool listens to which queue, so you can scale each type of job as needed.

Using EM reactor inside a request/response cycle is not recommended, because it may conflict with an existing event loop (for instance if your app is served by thin), in any case you have to configure it specifically for your web server, OTOS it may be interesting to have an evented queue consumer, if your jobs have blocking IO and are not processor-bound.

If you still want to do it with AMQP, see [Starting the event loop and connecting in Web applications](http://rdoc.info/github/ruby-amqp/amqp/master/file/docs/ConnectingToTheBroker.textile#Starting_the_event_loop_and_connecting_in_Web_applications__Ruby_on_Rails__Sinatra__Merb__Rack_)  and configure for your web server accordingly. Or use [bunny](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny) to push synchronously in the queue (and whichever job consumer you deam useflu, like workling for instance)

Answer (score 0):

we are running slightly different -- but similar technology stack.

daemon kit is used for eventmachine side of the system... no rails, but shared models (mongomapper & mongodb). EM is pulling messages off the queues, and doing whatever logic is required (we have ruleby in the mix, but if-then-else works too).

mulesoft ESB is our outward-facing message receiver and sender that helps us deal with the HL7/MLLP world. But in v1 of the app, we used some java code in ActiveMQ to manage HL7 messages.

the rails app then just serves up stuff for the user to see -- again, using the shared models.